# Include form in multiple templates for GenericForeignKey model (CBV)

Tags: python, django, forms, generics, django-class-based-views

To learn more about Django and understand how to program as DRY as possible, I'm building a small website with a couple of features:

- Post Blog
- Post Image
- Post Bookmark

On every object in these APPs, users can post a comment. So I got
a Comment APP with a model that takes a GenericForeignKey. (Properly working)

I want to display a comment form in the Detail view of the Blog, Image, and Bookmark. To keep this dry, I created an inclusion tag

```
@register.inclusion_tag('comments/add_comment.html')
def show_comment_form(obj):
    pk = obj.pk
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    form = AddCommentForm()

    return {'pk': pk, 'content_type': content_type, 'form': form}
```

Which uses the following template for rendering the form:

```
<form action="{% url 'comments:add' pk content_type %}" method="post">
    <div class="create-blog-container">
        <div class="box-top">{% trans "Leave your comment behind" %}...</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_div }}
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green" value="{% trans 'Add comment' %}" />
        </div>
</form>
```

When adding

```
{% show_comment_form blog %}
```

In the detail template of the blog, it renders the form with the right parameters. When I hit the SUBMIT button, the form is handled in the following Add view (currently just takes the form, validates, and adds it to the database via a service).

```
class Add(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    model = Comment

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        content_type = self.kwargs.get('content_type')
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        form = AddCommentForm(self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.cleaned_data.get('content')
            comments.services.comment.add(content_type, pk, self.request.user, content)
            messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, _("Your comment has been posted"))
        else:
            print(form.errors)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogs:detail', kwargs={'pk': pk}))
```

But this solution does not render back the form with validation errors. I went back to the basics to create a 'hard-coded' form in the blog's detail view, but it's not flexible nor DRY.

Can somebody give me a push in the right direction how to convert this form (via an inclusion tag, or other suggested method) into a DRY and flexible form to post a comment on a generic content_type?

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete DRY I suggest (as you mentioned) implementing commenting for [Django contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) and mixing it with AJAX.

Another one for your case it's possible to pass validated form to you inclusion tag (`show_comment_form`)

```
@register.inclusion_tag('comments/add_comment.html')
def show_comment_form(obj, form=None):
    pk = obj.pk
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    form = form or AddCommentForm()

    return {'pk': pk, 'content_type': content_type, 'form': form}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your inclusion tag, so it will post comment for on different URL, depending on object type. Also change it, so it won't make new form if there is already `comment_form` in current context. Example:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('comments/add_comment.html', takes_context=True)
def show_comment_form(context, obj):
    pk = obj.pk
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    form = context.get('comment_form', AddCommentForm())

    url_id = "%s:%s:comment:add" % (content_type.app_label, content_type.model)

    return {'pk': pk, 'content_type': content_type, 'form': form, url_id}
```

template:

```
{# content_type may be obsolete now #}
<form action="{% url url_id pk content_type %}" method="post">
    <div class="create-blog-container">
        <div class="box-top">{% trans "Leave your comment behind" %}...</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_div }}
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-green" value="{% trans 'Add comment' %}" />
        </div>
</form>
```

Create view mixin, that will add to your view handling comment creation (or form validation), create new views for each of your content types from normal view for that content and your new mixin and register that view on separate URL (name that url in way that you're creating `url_id` in your template tag).

It's dry, flexible and doesn't require lot of changes.